# Group and/or Select record functions in Crystal then sum specific values into one row

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Need help with following:

```
WO# -- Part# -------Inv# ------Cost  
1111 --AAAA  -------NULL ------45.00  
1111 --PARTFIX ---AAAA -------2.50  
1111 --BBBB -------NULL ------22.00  
1111 --PARTFIX ---BBBB -----37.50  
3333 --CCCC -------NULL ------2.55  
3333 --PARTFIX ---CCCC ------(1.50)
```

PARTFIX = price adjustment to original part charge.
The Inv# is what links the price adjustment (PARTFIX) to the original part charge.

Therefore when Inv# is NULL you know that is the original part charge.

Need to have Crystal return following:

```
WO# --- Part# ---Total Cost (Cost plus PartFix)  
1111 --- AAAA  --47.50  
1111 --- BBBB ---59.50  
3333 --- CCCC ---1.05
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Group and/or Select record functions in Crystal then sum specific values into one row.

Need help with following:

```
WO# ------ Part# ----------Inv# --------Cost  
1111 ------AAAA  ----------NULL ------45.00  
1111 ------PARTFIX ------AAAA -------2.50  
1111 ------BBBB ----------NULL ------22.00  
1111 ------PARTFIX ------BBBB------37.50  
3333 ------CCCC ---------NULL -------2.55  
3333 ------PARTFIX ------CCCC-----(1.50)
```

PARTFIX = price adjustment to original part charge.
The Inv# is what links the price adjustment PARTFIX to the original part charge.
Therefore when Inv# is NULL you know that is the original part charge.

Need to have Crystal return following:

```
WO# -------- Part# -----Total Cost (Cost plus PartFix)  
1111 -------- AAAA  ----------47.50  
1111 -------- BBBB ----------59.50  
3333 -------- CCCC -----------1.05
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why question repeated 2 times?

Comment: My original post got marked -1 so I must have reposted it twice. Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Crystal but on the SQL side I would add a new column, then populate it with part#, then UPDATE it with Inv# WHERE Part# = "PARTFIX", then the new column should have all AAAA, BBBB, CCCC values on which you can total, grouping on the new and WO# columns.  It's been a while since I wrote code so it would take me a while to put it together, hopefully this helps a little.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Still not able to summarize results. I got a summarized total w/in Crystal, but I cannot get a summarized result.